# How can I open popover outside scroll?

Tags: css, angularjs

My problem is when popover comes out it always stay inside of scroll. So that when I need to see popover content I need to scroll down then I can see it. I use z index. But I can not show the popover out side of scroll. I am using angular popover.

If I use position fixed instead of absolute it always open aspect of window and I don't want it.

Comment: Please provide some sample code you're using right now to assist with helping you. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an aspect of how CSS works. You are using incompatible CSS techniques. A child element (popover) that is absolutely positioned cannot be rendered outside a parent element boundary with overflow restrictions (hidden or scroll). The overflow property tells the browser to enforce rendering restrictions on all child elements except ones with "fixed" position.

If you show your code, we can probably help you achieve your goal with some modifications.

*Edit*

With the example provided, all that needs to be done is to add a CSS rule to the .sectionone element for position: static

```
.sectionOne {
  position: static; // solution
  overflow-x: scroll; // in example provided
}
.table {
  width:1000px; // in example provided
}
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/DnRscvEkd3esB334Dlhj

Last table row at 2nd td there is a button if you click the button popover come. But it is hide to my scroll.